# ASP.NET Submit but don't validate?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a form that looks like this :

```
[ enterdata: [______] ; more data: [_____] ; (SUBMITBUTTON) ]

[ Filter: [_______] ; (SUBMITBUTTON) ]
```

The top half has validators. I want to be able to type into the Filter textbox and press enter to fire it's submit button - but when I press enter, it validates the top half of the form also.

How do I do this? I have all the controls in the top half on one ValidationGroup, and all of the controls on the bottom half in another.

Comment: What happens if you manually click the submit button on the Filter line? Does it still validate both?

Comment: Did you put a ValidationGroup on the buttons as well?

Comment: When I click the Filter's submit button, it doesn't validate the top half (this is what I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "all the controls", do you include the buttons? Buttons and validators need to have separate validation groups assigned in order to be mutually exclusive.

Please validate that both submit buttons have a validation group assigned, and that all validators have a validation group assigned corresponding to the button that should cause that validator to validate.

As an alternative, you can set `CausesValidation` to false on the filter button if there needs be no validation performed at all.

Comment: All controls in the top half including the buttons are validation group "staddgroup", and all of the bottom half including the button are "filtergroup". For the filter button it has CausesValidation on false. I'm baffled o___O

Comment: @rlb - Very bizarre. Are you able to reduce it to a working example you can add to your post?